# How to restore most recent versions of all backed up files?

Tags: windows-backup

I have a thumb drive with a Windows backup archive and I want to restore this backup to a new machine.

It seems that I have to select a backup date in order to restore files, but it only shows files that were backed up on that date.  I want to restore ALL files so that only the most recent versions that were backed up get restored so that my new system has all of the same files as my old as of the last backup.

I also believe it's possible to unzip the actual archive itself, but I want to verify there's no native approach before I begin exploring that option.